# Where's the location of the folder /Android/OBB using NoxPlayer

Tags: windows-10, filesystems, mobile-phone, emulator

I'm trying to edit a file, in a folder of a mobile game i play. I downloadwd NoxPlayer on my PC .
Where's the location of the folder /Android/OBB using NoxPlayer